# jQuery ajax in ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

We have some code(simplified) that looks like bellow. We run function `x` which does an ajax call. When the call is done we call a different function `recalculateOrderObjects` which also does an ajax call. When this one is completed, it should output the data that which is obtained via the second call. However, what actually happens is that only the first ajax call is made and the second is not executed (or at least immediately goes to done) but does show the data obtained from the first call as the data obtained from the second one.

When running only the `recalculateOrderObjects` function the function does work as expected.

**Edit 1**

- The `subscription` variable is a global
- There are no errors on the console
- Also, when I first call `recalculateOrderObjects` independent the function work when first `x` is called and after that I call `recalculateOrderObjects` independently the function will not work and shows the same behaviour as when called from `x.'

**Edit 2**

I tried the suggestion to use `success`instead of `done`as well. With the same result. `recalucateOrderObjects` is called succesfully, thought after one executing `x` the whole ajax call in `recalucateOrderObjects` is never requested again but instead thinks that it is succesfully executed.

```
    function recalculateOrderObjects() {

        $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: url + "something",
                data: {data: subscription}
            })
            .done(function (data) {
                console.log('Data ' + data);

        });

    }
    function x(){

      jQuery.ajax({
        type: "get",
        dataType: "json",
        url: url,
        async: false
      }).done(function (response) {
            recalculateOrderObjects();
        }
      });}

  x();
```

Comment: There's not enough context in your question in order to diagnose the problem.

Comment: does console show you any error?

Comment: @MarkoMackic no there are no errors.

Comment: Get rid of this line from the first call: `async: false`. Does it work now?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov nope, added `async` and `cache` to try if it could have anything todo with this but both have no effect on the issue

Comment: What about this: `dataType: "json"`?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov nope still the same

Comment: @RoelVeldhuizen Note that, if an error does occur with the request, `jQuery.ajax()` won't `throw` it for the Console to show. You'll have to add an `error` option or `.fail()` callback to inspect the details.

Comment: Then I am clueless. A https://jsfiddle.net/ repro of your issue would definitely help.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski, the OP mentioned that there are no errors in the console. If the first AJAX call have failed, this would have resulted in an error message printed in the console.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov It may, though it depends on the error and the browser. Errors with the underlying XHR are often logged regardless of error-handling in the code in many browser. Though, errors that occur after the response is done (e.g. parser errors) will fail silently.

Comment: Any change if you add preventdefault() to the first function?Also httpfox addon for firefox is incredibly helpful to see the headers.

Comment: Things to help debug: View the Network tab of the browser tools and see what the response to the ajax call is (Could be an error, which you're not handling) and put breakpoints at the beginning of each callback.

Comment: Can you verify that the timestamps in the headers of each response are the same? My guess is a server error and you are actually hitting the same endpoint twice due to a routing issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can't get success responce by ".done" function.

"success" function gives you responce after ajax load.
Please try below code

```
function recalculateOrderObjects() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: url + "something",
        data: {data: subscription},
        success: function(data) {
            console.log('Data ' + data);
        }
    });
}
function x(){
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "get",
        dataType: "json",
        url: url,
        success: function(data) {
            recalculateOrderObjects();
        }
    });
}
x();
```

OR

```
function x(){
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "get",
        dataType: "json",
        url: url,
        success: function(data) {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: url + "something",
                data: {data: subscription},
                success: function(data) {
                    console.log('Data ' + data);
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
x();
```

Comment: tried it and tried it again after your suggestion. The issue is the same

Comment: "*You can't get success responce by ".done" function.*" For `$.ajax()`, the `success` option and `.done()` callbacks behave the same – they're called in the same cases with the same arguments. See [`jqXHR`'s documented methods](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR). They're only different if you're using a version of jQuery [older than 1.5](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/).